# Getting "Source not found" when debugging my own files on android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

This problems occurs when I'm debugging any android application on eclipse. Let´s say I've got 2 classes, each on a different file but on the same package:

```
             public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
<BREAKPOINT>       DummyClass.doSomething();
                }
             ...
             }

    ----------------

             public class DummyClass {

                public static diSomething(){
                   Log.e("TAG","HELLO");
                }
             }
```

When the execution stops at the breakpoint, I want to step into, to get to the DummyClass. However, I get a "Source not found" error, saying that android.jar is not accessible. Why? I'm not even trying to access that code.

I would appreciate much any help you you give me.

Comment: Call the constructor of super class `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and then try debugging again.

Comment: Hello Onik. This is a simplified version of the code. Of course, in real life, I would call the constructor and everything. That is not the point. The point is that the debugger's "step into" feature is not working.

Comment: `MainActivity` is not appropriately created because of the mentioned line missing. This might be the reason of _Source not found_ window showing up in the debugger for the simplified snippet.

Comment: Onik, Thanks you for your help. Again, I obviously have included the call to the super constructor in my project. However, rather than copy pasting hundreds of lines of code into this post, I decided to write a slimed-down version of the problem.

Main point, I don't have a problem with the code. It compiles and runs. I have a problem with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a spelling mistake in your code.

You have `DummyClass.doSomething();`and

```
public class DummyClass {

                public static *diSomething*(){
                   Log.e("TAG","HELLO");
                }
             }
```

Change it to `'doSomething()'` instead of diSomething()

Comment: Hello Ramakishna, Thanks for pointing out that the code has spelling errors. I wrote it directly into the post, so there are may thing that would cause it not to compile.

However, the question stands. When the code compiles and runs (and it does) when it reaches the breakpoint I can't use the debugger "step into" feature.